# Is it frowned upon to ask for help homebrewing a class on this forum?

Tags: discussion, homebrew

I've been here for a little while and wanted to ask this before I went asking a question that could be less acceptable than this one. I want some help homebrewing a class for 5e, but before I do, I figured I should ask if it's acceptable to so so. Sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: This should be asked on the [meta] site. Also, the site is not actually a forum. It's designed for question-and-answer posts, rather than open discussion threads.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance!

Comment: It's been moved to meta now.

Comment: Related: ["How do we ask for homebrew suggestions?"](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5782), ["Are “critique my home-brewed content” questions on topic?"](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1398), ["'Homebrew a class for me' questions"](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5325)

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know (If im wrong and a mod sees this pls comment) you can do homebrew, if you cant on the "forum" then im almost positive you can on the chatroom.